# Rest Api Arguments in in C#/ IIS seems too long

Tags: c#, windows, rest, iis

I'm totally new in web development and I tried to create a simple rest api in **vs2019/windows server 2016** for evaluation purpose.

My case/issue is as follows. I have a simple controller which has a 2 argument(string, string) method. If the whole request utf8 string is > 2101 characters the server returns a 404 in general.

I test this limitless time, with a dummy (**"AAAAA....."**) request string. 2002 length fails and 2001 length works. I tried to fix `web.config` but without luck, now I have a `maxQueryStringLength exception`.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Is it a `Get` API ?

Comment: would it make sense to put all your parameters in the URL, and why you are not trying to send your parameters using the body ?

Comment: You're running up against an extreme case here. General guideline is that URLs shouldn't be longer than ~2000 characters because unexpected things start happening. There is a pretty good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers).

Answer (score 0):

In your site web.config, add the following configuration (modifying existing elements when they are present, otherwise adding new elements):

```
<system.webserver>
  <security> 
    <requestFiltering> 
      <requestLimits maxUrl="65535" maxQueryString="65535"/> 
    </requestFiltering> 
  </security> 
</system.webServer>
```

and

```
<system.web> 
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="65535" maxUrlLength="65535" maxQueryStringLength="65535" />
</system.web>
```

do not forget to restart the site or iis after doing changes.